# Dynamically assign user roles

Tags: 7, users

I have an application using domain access and am looking to reuse a set of subscriber roles across domains, assigning them on login.

I was hoping to use [hook_user_load](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_load/7) to add the additional roles.

I have some code like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_user_load()
 * 
 * Dynamically assign configured roles based on active domain and subscription
 */
function EXAMPLE_user_load($users) {

  // Process each account once per request
  $processed_uids = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__, array());
  // Get defined roles
  $roles = user_roles(TRUE);

  // Process accounts
  foreach ($users as $uid => $account) {
    $grant_rids = array();
    if(!in_array($uid, $processed_uids)){
      // Code to get grant role ids here...
      // ...
      // ...
      // Grant subscriber roles
      if(!empty($grant_rids)){
        foreach($grant_rids as $rid){
          // Matching role exists and not already assigned
          if(!empty($roles[$rid]) && !array_key_exists($rid, $users[$uid]->roles)){
            $users[$uid]->roles[$rid] = $roles[$rid];
          }
        }
      }
      $processed_uids[] = $uid;
    }
  }
}
```

Using this approach, the roles do get added, and I can see them in the `$users` array after processing.

However the user logging in, despite running through `hook_user_load` doesn't appear to have those roles "set" ( i.e aren't authenticated as having that role )

Maybe some kind of cache issue?

Does anyone have any ideas about what needs changing above or how to assign user roles dynamically as the user logs in, or as the user is loaded?

**UPDATE:**

Well, it turns out, you *can* actually alter user roles in `hook_user_load`.

My issue was caused by a ctools bug I discovered in my debug travels whereby the current logged in user context didn't fully load the user entity, and thus the access checks for the Panel page access were failing. It also needed a `drupal_static_reset('user_access')` to reset the static `user_access` permission check cache. Patch posted here http://drupal.org/node/2010124

After that, the dynamic role assignment appears to be working fine.

**UPDATE 2**

I wrote too soon, still having problems...

Will update when resolved.

**UPDATE 3**

OK, the remaining issues were related to ctools context caching.
I ended up writing my own ctools access plugin to ensure the logged in user context is checked uncached on each access request. After that, all appears well again.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [user_multiple_role_edit](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_multiple_role_edit/7), something like this might help.

  `$user_id = $user->uid;
  // user the role human name
  $role_name = 'My Awesome Role';
  if (user_role_load_by_name($role_name)) {
    // No need to check if the role is already granted
    user_multiple_role_edit(array($user_id), 'add_role', $role->rid);
  }`

Comment: Thanks, but I want to assign the user roles dynamically, e.g on user load, without saving the roles to the database. The reason is a user may have 'subscriber' role on one domain, but not on another. The role should be assigned on login / load.

Comment: can you do a custom table? something like 

|role_name| user_id| domain| 
'subscriber' | 1 | 'some.domain.com'
'subscriber' | 1 | 'another.domain.com'

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [hook_user_load()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_load/7) contains a warning about overriding the user properties that are loaded from the {users} table, but apparently that is valid for properties loaded from the {users_roles} table read from [UserController::attachLoad()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/UserController%3a%3aattachLoad/7).

The only workaround I found is to alter the global `$user` variable, or change what shown in the user edit form when shown. The other possibility is changing the user roles when the user object is saved.
In a module I developed, I took the first approach.

Comment: Thanks kiamlaluno, I had found when using `EntityFieldQuery` that user roles weren't treated as a "property" of the user entity, so had assumed that was the case for the `hook_user_load` usage also. However, yes, perhaps there is some inconsistency of user role/property treatment in Drupal here. I'll have a go with altering `global $user` in an additional `user_login_submit` handler and perhaps also `hook_boot` to test. Will update when verified. Thanks again.

Comment: OK, it appears it actually _is_ possible to alter roles in `hook_user_load`. My issue was caused by a ctools bug I discovered whereby the current logged in user context didn't fully load the user entity ( patch posted here https://drupal.org/node/2010124 )

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly certain that modifying hook_user_load as suggested above will not actually allow you to assign a role dynamically to a user. Even though doing this will show that role during the hook_user_login hook; the user does not actually get logged in authenticated with that new role.

Comment: Just noting, I did get this feature working using `hook_user_load` as per above - it also needs `drupal_static_reset('user_access')`